# How to change useless repeat Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working with react-router for the first time.

Here is my piece of code.

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/A/xx/xxx/:feeros" component={About} />
    <Route path="/B/xx/xxx/:feeros" component={About} />
    <Route path="/C/xx/xxx/:feeros" component={About} />
    <Route path="/D/xx/xxx/:feeros" component={About} /> 
  </Switch>
```

This part of the `<Route path="//xx/xxx/:feeros" component={About} />` code is always repeated.There is no way to reduce this react router ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to handle four specific routes (A | B | C | D);

```
<Route path="/(A|B|C|D)/xx/xxx/:feeros" component={About} />
```

If you still need to intercept the parameter, but the values ​​can only be A | B | C | D, then you can write this:

```
<Route path="/:letter(A|B|C|D)/xx/xxx/:feeros" component={About} />
```

You will have two parameters:

```
const { letter, feeros } = match.params;
```

letter can only be: "A", "B", "C" or "D"

You can use another regular expression.

for example so:

```
<Route path="/([a-zA-Z])/xx/xxx/:feeros" component={About} />
```

The route will work for one Latin letter, for example:

```
'/A/xx/xxx/value'
'/s/xx/xxx/value'
'/F/xx/xxx/value'
```

Moreover, you can use regular expressions for parameters:

```
<Route path="/([a-zA-Z])/xx/xxx/:feeros(\d{2})" component={About} />
```

Matches routes with two-digit feeros values:

```
'/A/xx/xxx/11'
'/s/xx/xxx/21'
'/F/xx/xxx/45'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Route Params](https://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/route-params).

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/:letter/xx/xxx/:feeros" component={About} />
</Switch>
```

On the component side you can grab the parameter value:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { match: { params } } = this.props;

  console.log(params.letter);
  console.log(params.feeros);
}
```

Comment: @OldPervert Check my edited answer. From my understanding this is what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: I do not like this idea.because, then I have to check whether letter = A, B, C, D

Comment: From your question I can't understand what is your final purpose other than this.

Comment: It is necessary to check letter.Letter can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

you could have a paramter to identitfy: `A`, `B`, etc.

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/:id/xx/xxx/xx" component={About} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: you can use `:name` to identify dynamic params, then access `match.params` in your component props `/:id/xx/xxxx/:feeros`.